# How to store wise data in a chunks in multiple csv files from list of tuples

Tags: python, list, csv, tuples

I have a list of tuples and I need to write this data in multiple CSV files based on ranges like 500 data in each and every CSV file.

The example of data_list:

```
data_list = [(10.01,20.11),(34,20),(33,88),(44,90),(43,99)]
```

In above list I want two tuple in one csv file. so form this I will be having 3 csv file.

```
output_csv_file_01.csv 
output_csv_file_02.csv
output_csv_file_03.csv
```

I need multiple CSV files with the data_list data, with the given range.
for example: If I have 20000 data in the list, but I want only 5000 data rows in each csv file. so my output will be 4 csv files, each contains 5000 rows.

```
output_csv_file_01.csv 
output_csv_file_02.csv
output_csv_file_03.csv
output_csv_file_04.csv
```

I have this code snipit:

```
field = ['A','B']
data_list = [(10.01,20.11),(34,20),(33,88),(44,90),(43,99)]
with open(csv_filename, 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = fieldnames
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()       
    if data_list:
        for row in data_list:
        writer.writerow(
                        {"A": row[0],
                         "B": row[1]})
    else:
        print("{} {} not found".format(row[0], row[1]))
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @deadshot how to write chunks of data_list in multiple csv file.

Comment: can you show the expected output

Comment: @deadshot I need csv files as an output with the "data_list" data. I will update my question

Comment: my question is data in each csv file different or not and as per your code you writing same data to all csv files

Comment: @deadshot consider in my list I am having 5 tuples and my range is 2 rows in each csv file, so First csv file contains 2 tuples, Second csv file contains another 2 tuples, third csv file contains 1 tuple.   like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested loop. Outer loop will divide the list into sublists. And using inner loop you can write the sublist data to file.

You can change the `rows_per_file` as needed

```
import csv
data_list = [(10.01,20.11),(34,20),(33,88),(44,90),(43,99)]


fields = ['A','B']
file_name = 'output_csv_file_'
file_number, rows_per_file = 1, 2

for i in range(0, len(data_list), rows_per_file):
    with open(f'{file_name}{file_number}.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(fp, fieldnames=fields)
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in data_list[i: i + rows_per_file]:
            writer.writerow(dict(zip(fields, row)))
        file_number += 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much @deadshot